# Simplification of this function

Tags: functions

$f(x)= ((1- 4x^2)^{1/2} - 2(3)^{1/2}x)/((3-12x^2)^{1/2} + 2x)$
 Find range when $x$ belongs to $(-(3)^1/2 /4 ,1/2)$

[image: My work]

I have to find the range of this function , I have simplified this expression , I want to know that can I simplify it further more.

Original question was $ \tan^{-1}( ((1- 4x^2)^{1/2}  - 2(3)^{1/2}x)/((3-12x^2)^{1/2} + 2x))$ 
Find range in $(-(3)^1/2 /4 ,1/2)$

Comment: I got the range as $[\frac{-8}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}]$

Comment: Can you simplify this expression further ?

Comment: No but do you know the correct answer so that I can verify my answer because giving wrong answer will be pointless;)

Comment: I know answer but the question was bit different , it was tan inverse(f(x))

Comment: Can you post the original equation

Comment: I like Berhouz Maleki's approach below.  It is a clever substitution.  But, I don't know if I would expect most people to see that right away.  On the work done above.  First, I would suggest you rationalize the denominator, rather than the numerator, as you have done.  Second, always check the end points.

Comment: I have attached original question also ..

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

let $x=\frac{1}{2}\sin t$ ,$\,-\frac{\pi}{2}\le t \le\frac{\pi}{2}\, $  we have 
$$y=\frac{\cos t-\sqrt{3}\sin t}{\sqrt{3}\cos{t}+\sin t}=\frac{\cos\left(t+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)}{\sin\left(t+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)}=\cot\left(t+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)$$
let $x=\frac{1}{2}\sin t$ ,$\,\frac{\pi}{2}< t \le \pi\, $  we have 
$$y=\frac{-\cos t-\sqrt{3}\sin t}{-\sqrt{3}\cos{t}+\sin t}=-\frac{\cos\left(t-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)}{\sin\left(t-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)}=-\cot\left(t-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)$$

Comment: How does it help? Can you explain.

Comment: What was the idea in your mind that you should replace it with this?